# Access Json object name

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I want to get data with request.data.columns in frontend.I can do it with ViewSet with list method but how to do it with generics.APIView.
Below is my viewsets and generics code:

```
class TestList(viewsets.ViewSet):
     queryset = Test.objects.all()
     def list(self,request):
         serializer = TestSerializer(self.queryset, many = True)
         return Response({'columns': serializer.data})

class TestList(generics.RetriveAPIView):
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Show your urls.py / router code.

Comment: This is my url path --> path('getTest/', TestList.as_view(), name='getTest'),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class TestList(APIView):
     queryset = Test.objects.all()
     def list(self,request):
         serializer = TestSerializer(self.queryset, many = True)
         return Response({'columns': serializer.data})
```

change your urls.py like this.

```
path(r"url", TestList.as_view({"get": "list"}))
```

Comment: After trying this I have this error, "as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".

Comment: Thanks jackquin for your response. I had to do some changes in your given code,I add queryset = self.get_queryset() after list method and I don't have to change the url path.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code:

```
class TestList(APIView):
     queryset = Test.objects.all()
     def list(self,request):
         queryset = self.get_queryset()
         serializer = TestSerializer(queryset, many = True)
         return Response({'columns': serializer.data})
```

Details about why i had to add queryset = self.get_queryset() instead of directly access self.queryset.From official drf documentation:

**queryset** - The queryset that should be used for returning objects from this view. Typically, you **must** either set this attribute, or **override** the get_queryset() method. If you are overriding a view method, it is important that you call get_queryset() instead of accessing this property directly, as queryset will get evaluated once, and those results will be cached for all subsequent requests.